# Union tables and displaying them in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I apologize if my wording is confusing but I have a question regarding three tables I want to union and then displaying them in a html table, because I am unsure if the way I am doing it now is correct. I have three tables, one named "Patients" that has 3 columns, "Patient_Records" which has 5 columns, and "Patient_App" that also have 5 columns. Then in my html table I have 13 columns. I created null values for the patient table but I am unsure if the way I am displaying them is correct.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
  <title>Page Title</title> 
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 
  <h1>Patient Records</h1>
  <div class = "center">
    <table style="width:60%">
      <tr>
        <th>Patient First Name</th>
        <th>Patient Last Name</th>
        <th>Patient ID</th>
        <th>Date of Birth</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Patient Address & Cell</th>
        <th>Shots Given</th>
        <th>Illness</th>
        <th>Appointment Date</th>
        <th>Appointment Type</th>
        <th>Procedure Date</th>
        <th>Procedure Type</th>
        <th>Doctor</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <?php

          require_once('/afs/cad.****/u/a/m/***/public_html/connect.php'); //private info in *
          $sql = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, PatientID, Null as col4, Null as col5 FROM Patients
          UNION
          SELECT DOB, Age, Addr&Phone, Shots, Illnes FROM Patient_Records
          Union
          SELECT AppDate, AppType, ProcedureDate, ProcedureType, Doctor FROM Patient_app";
          $result = $con-> query($sql);

          if($result-> num_rows > 0){
            while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()){
              echo "<tr><td>" . $row["FirstName"] . "</td><td>" . $row["LastName"] . "</td><td>" . $row["PatientID"] . "</td><td>" . $row["col4"] .  "</td><td>" . $row["col5"] . "</td></tr>"; 
            }
            echo "</table>";
          }
          else{
            echo "0 result";
          }
        $con-> close();
        ?>
    </table>

  </div>
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>  
</body> 
</html>
```

(I am not entirely finished with including every single column)
As you can see in the code above when I'm displaying the rows I include the null columns "$row[col4]". Is this necessary or do I skip this part out because it will just insert a blank cell because it technically doesn't exist in my original table?

Comment: Well those last 2 columns obviously exist in the unioned tables which are also part of your query results, so you'll need to echo those columns when you are displaying any records returned from those tables. So the `echo` makes sense the way you have it now, based on that.

Comment: You might not understand how `UNION` in SQL works and what it accomplishes.  I suggest working through a tutorial: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx or similar.

Comment: Of course, if you want to check whether the value in that field for a particular row is blank, and then decide not to print the cell on that row, you can do that. It's entirely your choice.

Comment: IMHO though, putting records from 3 different database tables into a single HTML table, without labelling what the different columns mean, or showing which table any given result is from, might be pretty confusing for the end users, don't you think?

Comment: And your table header contains far more columns than the query is actually going to output. The query only outputs 5 columns. I think PM 77-1 might be right... I wonder if you don't really understand what a UNION query produces. Try running that query in MySQL directly (e.g. via phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench) before you put it into PHP, so you can see what the output is going to be. I suspect it's not the output you were actually hoping for. You might need a bit of a rethink of the SQL code.

Comment: Also I wonder a bit about your database design overall. What is the difference between the `Patients` and `Patient_Records` tables? They both seem to store key data about the patient. I would have thought `DOB, Age, Addr&Phone` all ought to be in the `Patients` table. Otherwise you'll end up needing to pointlessly repeat those records every time you record a single episode of illness or an injection record.

Comment: @PM77-1 I know I am not using UNION for it's original purpose. It's that I just couldn't really understand anyway I could join the three tables because none of them have columns with the same info.

Comment: `none of them have columns with the same info`...this also sounds like a fundamental design flaw. How do you tell which procedures have been given to which patient, then?? I would expect that you need to have `PatientID` in as a foreign key in the `Patient_Records` and `Patient_app` tables, and then to find the records for a specific patient you would `SELECT ... WHERE PatientID = ?`. I doubt you need either a UNION or a JOIN - these look like separate datasets which should display in different HTML tables, not one gigantic table (which would inevitably repeat lots of the patient's basic data)

Comment: @ADyson I agree with you about how DOB, Age, and addre&phone should be in the same table. That part is unfortunately out of my control because that is how my professor instructed us to create our tables. And my professor also wants to display all three of those tables into one big table. I would not have designed it like this either.

Comment: So I think actually maybe a course on the fundamentals of relational database design is in order, as well as some careful thought about how you want to present this info to end users in a meaningful and efficient way. Even as a student project, it's a good idea to get into these concepts and explore them, and try to get good at it.

Comment: `that is how my professor instructed us`...are you 100% sure about that? Or is that maybe a "deliberate mistake" on the professor's part, because they want you to spot the design flaw and challenge it?

Comment: `And my professor also wants to display all three of those tables into one big table`...really? Again it will make a mess. Are you sure you aren't supposed to challenge that? Or maybe you just have a terrible professor...it's hard to tell.

Comment: @ADyson Nope that is how my instructor instructed us to go about it. Create three tables in phpadmin and then combine them into one table in an html page. I understand that you think they may be trying to trick us but they are not.

Comment: @ADyson based off of ratemyprofessor and other students in their course I have a terrible professor

Comment: Yeah it sounds like a pretty goofy assignment from that point of view. Anyway though you certainly need the PatientID foreign keys before you can make this work in a sensible way. And then you'll probably need to use INNER JOINs to join the 3 tables based on the selected patient ID, to get all the records in the (very silly) format requested by your tutor (I think, from what I've seen, calling them any kind of "Professor" is overstating the case significantly! Where I come from, Professor is an official and esteemed senior academic title, it's not handed out to any old half-baked teacher!).